# What is equivalent features of WPF in QtQuick?

Tags: wpf, qt, xaml, qml, qt-quick

I am a WPF programmer. But i see some weakness on WPF (see [this my replay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706037/what-are-the-real-world-benefits-of-declarative-ui-languages-such-as-xaml-and-qm/8337465#8337465)). So i curious to research for QtQuick.
WPF has some great features such as:

- Hardware accelerated
- Animations and effects
- Triggers( Trigger, DataTrigger, EventTrigger)
- Resources
- Templates
- Commands
- Binding
- Good for MVVM Pattern
- Geometries
- Clip mask and Gradient and composing controls
- Creating SilverLight version of application for web

What is equivalents of these features on QtQuick?

Comment: I've deleted my answer because you've turned this into a vague meandering discussion.  See paragraph 1 and 2 from ["What kind of questions should I not ask here?" in the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: Wow... Excuse me, i'm newbie on Stackoverflow :( But it is so near to i checking it as answer !!!